# How to insert char array into another char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I want to insert some text (char array) into another char array. I used for this strcpy, but it sometimes shows (not always) strange signs, take a look:

[image]

how to get rid of them?

Heres my code:

```
    #include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const string currentDateTime() {
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm tstruct;
    char buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%X", &tstruct);
    return buf;
}

char *addLogin(char *login, char buf[])
{
    string b(buf);
    string l(login);
    string time = currentDateTime();
    string res = time;
    res += l;
    res += b;
    return const_cast<char*>(res.c_str());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[1024];
    strcpy(buf, " some text");
    char *login = "Brian Brown";
    char *temp = addLogin(login, buf);
    strcpy(buf, temp);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDITED:**

```
const string currentDateTime() {
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm tstruct;
    char buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%X", &tstruct);
    string b(buf);
    return b;
}
```

and it seems to work well for now

Comment: In memset why `&buf` it should be `buf` only since array name will give the address

Comment: Isn't this what sprintf is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the function `currentDateTime()`, you return a local variable `buf` which is undefined behaviour.  This is certainly cauing problem when you later append the strings (along with the one returned by this function).

Besides, the signature of the function is `const string` but you return a `char*`.